# absract factory methods uses in Android

Tags: android

When to use abstact factory method in android?

Comment: Someone down voted this question. May i know why??

Answer (score 2):

I am in a project which have required Analytic both from Google and Firebase. So I decided to use Abstract factory for my case.

`AnalyticFactory`:Abstract class which have some method such as: `trackActivity` `trackFragment` `trackEvent`. And one static method called `createFactory` which input is `FactoryType` (Firebase or Google) and return my `Analytic` based on my choice

`FireBaseFactory` and `GoogleFactory`: Child class inherit from `AnalyticFactory`.

After I implemented both FireBase and Google Factory. I just used it by `AnalyticFactory`. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

I usually read a document about design pattern from [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/index.htm). It is easier to understand. This one is [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm)

Comment: i know what is abstract factory pattern, i just wanted to know the examples of it in terms of android.